# Implement a simple chat server with akka and scala

Tags: scala, akka

I am learning Akka and Scala and trying to build a simple chat server with it. I wrote the below code to create a simple session manager to manage new created Actors. I am able to create new actors and put the ActorRef to a HashMap, however when I try to send message to a particular Actor the message just can't be received by the Actor.

Here is the code.

```
import akka.actor.{ ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor, Inbox }
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap


case class ChatMsg(from:String,message:String)
case class Login(username:String)

class Session(userID:String) extends Actor{
    val loginTime = System.currentTimeMillis
    println(s"Session created time :$loginTime")
    def receive ={
    case ChatMsg(from,message) => println(s"message :$message from    $from !")
    }
}

class SessionManager extends Actor{
val system = ActorSystem("ChatSession")
val sessions = new HashMap[String,ActorRef]
val inbox = Inbox.create(system)

def receive ={
    case Login(username) =>
        println(s"$username Login, now create Actor")
        val session = system.actorOf(Props(new Session(username)))
        sessions += (username->session)
        println(s"session added $sessions")
    case ChatMsg(from,message) => 
        sessions(from) ! message 

}
}



object MyAkkaTest extends App {

val system = ActorSystem("MyAkkaTest")
val user = system.actorOf(Props[SessionManager],"MyActor")
val inbox = Inbox.create(system)
user ! Login("Mary")
user ! Login("John")
user ! ChatMsg("Mary","this is a testing message") //this message can never sent...


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your Session actor, is expecting to get messages of type ChatMsg, but your are sending it a String.

Your main method is sending a ChatMsg object to the SessionManager actor. The SesionManager is receiving this, and via pattern matching extracting its to fields; from and message, both of type String. It then finds the relevant Session actor, and send it the message extracted from the ChatMsg object. It is therefore just sending the message part of the ChatMsg object, and not the ChatMsg object itself.

The easiest way to fix it, is to make the pattern matching in the receive method of SessionManager, bind a name for the actual ChatMsg object received, and then send that to the Session actor. You can do this by prefixing your pattern match with a "name" @ pattern:

```
class SessionManager extends Actor{
    val system = ActorSystem("ChatSession")
    val sessions = new HashMap[String,ActorRef]
    val inbox = Inbox.create(system)

    def receive ={
        case Login(username) =>
            println(s"$username Login, now create Actor")
            val session = system.actorOf(Props(new Session(username)))
            sessions += (username->session)
            println(s"session added $sessions")
        case chatMsg @ ChatMsg(from,message) =>
            sessions(from) ! chatMsg

    }
}
```

Comment: That's helped a lots! Thanks!